# Oracle XE (11g) Pagination Fails. Cause: offset fetch fails with error: command not properly ended

Tags: oracle, hibernate, spring-data

I'm using spring boot 2.0.5.RELEASE and spring data jpa.

I want to use Pageable to control pagination.

The generated SQL is only valid for Oracle 12, not XE/Oracle 11.

Is this a known Hibernate issue? and is there a workaround?
Thanks.

Maven:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.5.RELEASE</version>
</parent>
```

Repository:

```
public List<Simple> findAll(Pageable pageable);
```

Spring Test Class:

```
list = simpleRepository.findAll(PageRequest.of(1, 1));
assertEquals(1, list.size());
```

Simplified SQL generated:

```
SELECT * FROM simple OFFSET 1 ROWS FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY;
```

Comment: Please show in the question the content of `application.properties` file, especially `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect` entry. You may append to this file the following entry: `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect`, and Hibernate should start to generate queries for Oracle 10 dialect, (using ROWNUM+subquery and without ROWS+OFFSET clause)

Comment: I didn't have that in my application.properties.
It solved the issue when I added it.

I was using the jdbc driver from Oracle XE, I thought I didn't have to set the dialect. I was hoping Spring Boot was smart enough to auto configure it.

Answer (score 1):

Add
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect
to
application.properties